# Moving .ghc and .cabal to a different user

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

How can I move the GHC and cabal installed packages to a different user? I've copied the directories but I'm getting error messages like:

```
ConfigParser.hs:15:8:
    Could not find module `Data.ByteString.Char8'
    There are files missing in the `bytestring-0.10.2.0' package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

`ghc-pkg check` shows that any file for any package is missing. How can I resolve this?

*Note:* This question intentionally does not show research effort, because it was answered Q&A-style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you obviously need to copy `.ghc` and `.cabal`. These contain the binary files and configurations.

For simplicity, we will assume moving from user `foo` to user `bar`. Note that moving between architectures is not possible, as the binaries produced by GHC are not platform-independent.

After copying the aforementioned directories, there are paths like `/home/foo` remaining in different locations. We will use `sed` to replace those (run this as `bar`):

```
sed -i -e "s/foo/bar/g" ~/.cabal/config
sed -i -e "s/foo/bar/g" ~/.ghc/*-*/package.conf.d/*.conf
```

However, the file `~/.ghc/*-*/package.conf.d/package.cache` still contains file references containing the username. We can't simply use `sed` to replace, however, because it's a binary file and it might destroy the package cache.

You can use `ghc-pkg recache --user` to re-cache all packages.

After performing these steps, you should be able to use the `cabal` packages as expected.